# IONIC: unable to load dynamic content in `ion-infinite-scroll`

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new with ionic framework.Currently i am working on `ionicsidemenu` app.

I have 100 plus records i want to display 20 records at once.   When scroll down get next 20 records.   For this i am using `ion-infinite-scroll` but i am unable to understand how to call next 20 records. I am  using webservice for fetching records.

Please help me.

Comment: IONICS documentation does a good job of giving an example of usage: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/.  If applicable, take note of the waitFor method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array instead of object in this case because pushing items in array is easier than pushing into object. Ionic documentaton also uses array in their example.

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">...</div>
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="getData()">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.data = [];
var page = 1;
$scope.getData = function(){
     $http.get('http://example.com?page='+page).then(function(response){
         page++;
         $.each(response,function(key,item){
             $scope.data.push(item);
         });
     }, function(error){

     });
}
```

When scroll reach to ion-infinite-scroll function will called. at beginning there is no data on screen so without scrolling ion-infinite-scroll function called automatically to load first page.

Comment: Thank you so much @sharad i'll try and let you know. :)

Comment: I have tried this but getData() not called, if i call getData() on `ng-init="getData();"` within ion content it loads data but when scroll nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

use limitTo together with Infinite scrolling. AngularJS ng-repeat offers from version 1.1.4 the limitTo option. I slightly adapted the Infinite Scroll directive to make scrolling within a container possible that does not have height 100% of window.

```
   ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:prop | filter:query | limitTo:limit"
```

Notice that limit is a variable in the $scope, so changing it automatically adjusts the number of rendered items. And incrementing limit, only renders the added elements.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data | limitTo:totalDisplayed"><td>{{d}}</td></tr>
</table>
<button class="btn" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</button>

//the controller
$scope.totalDisplayed = 20;

$scope.loadMore = function () {
  $scope.totalDisplayed += 20;  
};

$scope.data = data;
```

---

or try out this solution

```
<body>
    <pane ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <header-bar title="'Infinite Scroll Example'">
          </header-bar>
        <content has-header="true"  padding="true" on-infinite-scroll="addMoreItem">
          <div class=" list padding">
            <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:numberOfItemsToDisplay" class="item" type="item-text-wrap">
              <h3>{{item}}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </content>
    </pane>

  </body>
```

js code

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 20; // number of item to load each time
      $scope.items = getData(); 

      function getData() {
        var a = [];
        for (var i=1; i< 1000; i++) {
            a.push(i);
        }

        return a;
      }
      $scope.addMoreItem = function(done) {
        if ($scope.items.length > $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay)
          $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 20; // load 20 more items
        done(); // need to call this when finish loading more data
      }

    });
```

while on scrolling will display 20 items.

Comment: thank you so much @pritish for the answer. i need to get content with out click event as when user  touches  bottom of the page loadmore function called automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: I updated the answer @NupurJain plz check it out.  I have't tested it.

Comment: Or you can use UI-Scroll https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll/master/demo/chat/chat.html